# unexpected result from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm expecting the result in PowerShell as following but it was out of my expectation.  How do I correct it?
Expecting

```
FriendlyName    |    MediaType| PSComputerName|    Serial Number
------------    |    --------- |--------------  |  -------------
ST500DM002-1BD142|   3        | ABCD-IT       |    6CR4160X2H
Samsung SSD 250GB|   4        | ABCD-IT       |    6CR4160X2H
Result
FriendlyName     |   MediaType| PSComputerName|    Serial Number
------------     |   ---------| --------------|    -------------
ST500DM002-1BD142|   3        | ABCD-IT       |    @{serialnumber=6CR4160X2H}
Samsung SSD 250GB|   4        | ABCD-IT       |    @{serialnumber=6CR4160X2H}
```

Coding

```
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -ComputerName ABCD-IT -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage | Select FriendlyName, MediaType, pscomputername,@{name="Serial Number";expression={Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios | select serialnumber}}
```

Comment: `Select -ExpandProperty SerialNumber`

Comment: Are you looking for the disk- or the BIOS serial number?

Comment: Good catch, they may want the disk serial instead.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for bios serial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above, either `-ExpandProperty` or just drill down to the actual value:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -ComputerName localhost -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage | Select FriendlyName, MediaType, pscomputername,@{name="SerialNumber";expression={Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber}}
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -ComputerName localhost -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage | Select FriendlyName, MediaType, pscomputername,@{name="SerialNumber";expression={(Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios | Select-Object SerialNumber).SerialNumber}}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem fixed.